# Background Video Using Revolution Slider

Tags: wordpress, revolution-slider

I am looking to build a background video area using Revolution slider (w/ Wordpress) like this web site: https://www.leftronic.com/

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it is by adding custom CSS to the slider (using the purple <kbd>< /></kbd> button next to Save)

```
.tp-static-layers {
  z-index: 0 !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
}
```

Then add a video layer to the Global Slide and check **Fullscreen** and **Force Cover** from the sizing tab.